# Decrypt data with python, encrypt in php

Tags: php, python

I get the necrypted string to pycrypto ,but it returned a incorrect result.

```
<?php
define('MCRYPT_SECRET_KEY', '1d46a31baeab9cf69184d1f92ba5b9f8');
function decode($encode_str) {
    $key = pack('H*',MCRYPT_SECRET_KEY);
    //var_dump($key);echo "\n";
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    //var_dump($iv_size);echo "\n";
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    //var_dump($iv);echo "\n";

    $encode_str = str_replace(['-', '_'], ['+', '/'], $encode_str);
    $mod4 = strlen($encode_str) % 4 and $encode_str .= substr('====', $mod4);
    //var_dump($encode_str);echo "\n";
    $decrypt = base64_decode($encode_str);
    //var_dump($decrypt);echo "\n";
    $decrypt = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $decrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

    return $decrypt;
}
echo "aFOYNZB4Ye4 : ".decode("aFOYNZB4Ye4")."\n";
```

result:

```
aFOYNZB4Ye4 : 13455
```

but when I use python,I could not get the correct result.

```
# coding: utf-8
import sys,os,base64
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3

key = "1d46a31baeab9cf69184d1f92ba5b9f8".decode("hex")

def urlsafe_mcryptdecode(idstr):
    try:
        print len(key),key,'\n'
        idstr = idstr.replace('-','+').replace('_','/')
        mod4 = len(idstr) % 4
        data=idstr+"===="[mod4:]
        #print len(data),data,'\n'
        base64_str = base64.b64decode(data)
        #print len(base64_str),base64_str,'\n'
        cipher = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_ECB)
        id_ = cipher.decrypt(base64_str)
        #print len(id_),id_,'\n'
        return id_
    except Exception,e:
        print "ERROR",e
        return idstr+"#error"

print urlsafe_mcryptdecode("aFOYNZB4Ye4")
```

result is not 13455.

Before the decrypt,every result of all output is same. What's wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: Dncrypt? necrypt? Did you mean decrypt and encrypt?

Comment: if I run your same code, the result is `\x11\x88\xc7\x89\xd0Df\x94`.

Comment: but it's not 13455

Comment: 3DES and ECB are both poor choices. The current generally accepted encryption algorithm is AES. The problem with ECB is that each block is independent of all others so if two blocks have the same data the encrypted data will be the same, this applies to identical blocks in one encryption and also between different encryptions with the same key. The DES block size is 8-bytes. So the question to ask: "Is the use about just encrypting or creating security utilizing encryption."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that prior to PHP 5.6.0 the function `mcrypt_decrypt()` silently pads the key. Your key is 16 bytes, however, the key needs to be 24 bytes, and so it is padded internally to 24 bytes with trailing NUL bytes. This is mentioned in the newer PHP documentation for [`mcrypt_decrypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php) - see the Changelog section.

You need to take this into account when decrypting in Python. You can do that by appending NUL bytes to the end of the decoded key using `ljust()`:

```
key = "1d46a31baeab9cf69184d1f92ba5b9f8".decode("hex").ljust(24, '\0')
```

or

```
key = "1d46a31baeab9cf69184d1f92ba5b9f8".decode("hex") + ('\0' * 8)
```

I noticed that your PHP code generates an IV which it does not use. That's fine, it's not causing a problem, just thought I'd point that out in case you think that it's being used.

Incidentally, if you are using PHP >= 5.6.0, you need to explicitly pad the key, or use a 24 byte key in the first place. In your code you can pad like this:

```
$key = pack('H*x8', MCRYPT_SECRET_KEY);
```

which will append an additional 8 NUL bytes to the end of the key.

Comment: Awesome.Thanks a lot.